# Prevent machine from sleeping when SSH connections are on

Tags: ssh, power-management, suspend

I am trying to save power by switching desktops to suspend mode when they are inactive. But many desktops are also accessed via SSH by their owners. There is a wakeonlan solution deployed to enable owners to switch on the machine, but the problem is that machines will auto-suspend again in 10 minutes, even though the SSH connection is on.

What I am trying to do is to include the active SSH sessions in the "activity" definitions.

The question is can it be done via setting a polkit rule? Can it be done via putting a script that runs before the actual suspend, and aborts it if SSH sessions are found? I need a clean legit way of doing this. If not that, then hacky ways are also welcome.

Current naive hacky solution: edit `/usr/sbin/pm-suspend`:

```sh
#check for SSH sessions, and prevent suspending:
if [ "$(who | grep -cv "(:")" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "SSH session(s) are on. Not suspending."
    exit 1
fi
```

This serves the purpose. But I don't know when an update will overwrite the file `/usr/sbin/pm-suspend`. I also don't know how this will work with other suspend implementations like tuxonice.

Comment: May I suggest using `grep -cv :0` instead of passing through `wc`?

Comment: Another idea for more elegance: You can drop the invocation of `[` if you write `if who | grep -qv :0; then` (assuming you have a POSIX conforming `grep` like GNU grep).

Comment: who outputs times too, so ":0" is not unique to the console user (e.g. "15:07")

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Until Ubuntu 14.10 (Upstart-based)

Have a look at [`pm-action(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pm-hibernate.8.html) and search for `/etc/pm/sleep.d` in section “FILES”. If one of these scripts returns with a non-zero exit status, suspension is prevented.

Updated instructions for clarity:

1. So create a file `/etc/pm/sleep.d/05_ssh_keepawake`.
2. Put a [shebang](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (`#!/bin/sh`) and the code mentioned in the question in this file.
3. Set execute permissions on it:

   ```
   chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/05_ssh_keepawake
   ```

### Since Ubuntu 15.04 (systemd-based)

*systemd* doesn’t use *pm-utils* to manage its power state hooks but has its own infrastructure to the same end. Sleep inhibitor checkers are no longer executed on sleep but must be set *by the action that inhibits* sleep (see [1](//www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit)).

As such you’d have to add commands to the SSH session log-in and log-out that registers a sleep inhibitor with systemd (e. g. via [`systemd-inhibit(1)`](//manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/systemd-inhibit.1.html)) and later releases the inhibitor. If somebody knows how to hook into SSH log-in and log-out, I’d welcome a comment or edit so that we could work out the relevant steps and commands.

#### The following section is work in progress – Only use it when you know what you’re doing!

You might be able to write a systemd unit `/etc/systemd/system/ssh-inhibit-sleep.service` that makes itself a dependency of `sleep.target` using the `RequiredBy` option. If your new unit fails (with a non-zero exit status from its invoked process), it will make `sleep.target` and thus the subsequent sleep action.

```
[Unit]
Description=Check for running SSH sessions and, if any, inhibit sleep
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '! who | grep -qv "\(:0\)"'

[Install]
RequiredBy=sleep.target
```

As always you need to activate systemd units for them to take effect:

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh-inhibit-sleep.service
```

For more info see `systemd.unit(5)` and `systemd.service(5)`.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in 18.04. Is this no longer the solution?

Comment: @MichaelJarret: Indeed. I updated my question with some info on the situation with systemd.

Comment: I found the following while trying to sort this out yesterday, but couldn't modify the previous script to do the job [here](https://blog.christophersmart.com/2016/05/11/running-scripts-before-and-after-suspend-with-systemd/)

Comment: I can't edit my comment, but also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136548/force-command-to-be-run-on-logout-or-disconnect) seems relevant

Comment: @MichaelJarret: I noticed that blog post too. Unfortunately this method cannot be used to inhibit sleep as far as I know, only to perform particular operations on sleep and at wake-up, as far as I understand.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am going to write a daemon for the moment that checks in every so often and to see if an ssh user is connected and registers the sleep inhibitor, if the ssh user is disconnected for, say, 20 minutes, then I'll release the inhibitor. This isn't elegant, so further thoughts appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelJarret: I had another idea that you could try. See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Combining two related answers ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136552/84197) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/954943/388360)), here's an `/etc/pam_session.sh` that does the trick on Ubuntu 19.10 (at least):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script runs when an ssh session opens/closes, and masks/unmasks
# systemd sleep and hibernate targets, respectively.
#
# Inspired by: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136552/84197 and
#              https://askubuntu.com/a/954943/388360

num_ssh=$(netstat -nt | awk '$4 ~ /:22$/ && $6 == "ESTABLISHED"' | wc -l)

case "$PAM_TYPE" in
    open_session)
        if [ "${num_ssh}" -gt 1 ]; then
            exit
        fi
        command=mask
        ;;

    close_session)
        if [ "${num_ssh}" -ne 0 ]; then
            exit
        fi
        command=unmask
        ;;

    *)
        exit
esac

logger "${command}ing sleep and suspend targets (num_ssh=${num_ssh})"
sudo systemctl ${command} sleep.target suspend.target
```

Make sure to add the line:

```
session     optional    pam_exec.so quiet /etc/pam_session.sh
```

to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` in the `session` section, and make the `/etc/pam_session.sh` script executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/pam_session.sh
```

Note that the `/etc/pam_session.sh` script appears to run as the the user logging in or out, so that user requires `sudo` access to mask/unmask systemd targets.

Comment: Seems to be the most elegant solution. Despite its age, confirmed working on 20.10.
One step missing in the answer: Make sure to add the line `session     optional    pam_exec.so quiet /etc/pam_session.sh` to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` in the session part and make the `/etc/pam_session.sh` executable.

Comment: Thanks @emk2203, I will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

In modern **systemd** systems, you can also use the **ssh.socket** service together with **systemd-inhibit**. Instead of running the usual **ssh.service** standalone, you can let **systemd** manage the incoming connections. Each open session now gets handled by **ssh.socket** which creates the instance units based on **ssh@.service**, so it is just a matter creating a service that binds directly to that. This has the added benefit of tracking and logging each ssh connection with **systemd**. We can then use this identifier to provide more useful information when blocking sleep. This method also prevents degrading **systemd** with a failing unit like some other examples.

First you need to check to make sure to enable **ssh.socket** if you are not already using it.

```
systemctl is-active ssh.socket
```

Should say **active** otherwise you will need to enable it:

```
sudo systemctl disable ssh
sudo systemctl stop ssh
sudo systemctl enable ssh.socket
sudo systemctl start ssh.socket
```

Then you just need is to create **/etc/systemd/system/ssh-no-sleep@.service** with

```javascript
[Unit]
Description=ssh no sleep
BindsTo=ssh@%i.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-inhibit --mode block --what sleep --who "ssh session "%I --why "session still active" /usr/bin/sleep infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=ssh@.service
```

And enable it with:

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh-no-sleep@
```

In order for the ssh@.service alias (represented with the @) to be triggered you have to make sure your ssh.socket service has the **[Socket]** setting **Accept=yes**, otherwise the no sleep service will never trigger for each new connection. You can test your systemd default settings by running:

```
sudo systemctl show --no-pager --property Accept ssh.socket
```

If this returns **no**, you will need to override it to **yes** by creating a conf file **/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/accept.conf** with:

```javascript
[Socket]
Accept=yes
```

If your system is missing **ssh@.service** or **ssh.socket**, here is the one from Debian Bullseye as an example that you can work off of:

**/etc/systemd/system/ssh@.service**

```javascript
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server per-connection daemon
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=auditd.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStart=-/usr/sbin/sshd -i $SSHD_OPTS
StandardInput=socket
RuntimeDirectory=sshd
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
```

**/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket**

```javascript
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket
Before=sockets.target
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Socket]
ListenStream=22
Accept=no

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

After saving this, running **systemctl daemon-reload** and **systemctl restart ssh.socket** , you can re-run the prior show command to confirm **Accept=yes**

Now when someone tries to suspend, they will get a useful message of all the blocking ssh sessions

```
sudo systemctl suspend
```

Will then return something like:

```javascript
Operation inhibited by "ssh session 1/127.0.0.1:22/127.0.0.1:12345" (PID 12345 "systemd-inhibit", user root), reason is "session still active".
Operation inhibited by "ssh session 2/2001:db8:1::1:22/2001:db8:2::1:12345" (PID 54321 "systemd-inhibit", user root), reason is "session still active".
Please retry operation after closing inhibitors and logging out other users.
Alternatively, ignore inhibitors and users with 'systemctl suspend -i'.
```

Added benefit of **ssh.socket** is that you can also use:

```
systemctl status ssh.socket
```

Which returns active users and system stats:

```javascript
* ssh.socket - OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (listening) since Mon 2021-12-20 14:46:05 EST; 1h 6min ago
   Triggers: * ssh@2-2001:db8:1::1:22-2001:db8:2::1:12345.service
             * ssh@1-127.0.0.1:22-127.0.0.1:12345.service
     Listen: [::]:22 (Stream)
   Accepted: 2; Connected: 2;
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 18775)
     Memory: 16.0K
        CPU: 2ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.socket
```

Comment: sadly it looks like ssh.socket was removed starting in openssh 8.0p1-3 because it was susceptible to DDOS

Comment: @phiresky ssh.socket and ssh@.service systemd units have nothing to do with openssh version. It is up to the package maintainer for your specific distro to include it or not. I can confirm it works just fine in latest Debian and probably all Debian derivatives. You can just copy the missing systemd unit files from them. I disagree with Arch package maintainers for no longer including those units based on DDoS concerns as it doesn't line up with my threat model. Security is a balance and different distros have different opinions.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Can you explain the `@` in the file name? Is that your personal preference or is that some necessary magic?

Comment: @Harald the ```@``` indicates a systemd template¹ ```service@argument.service``` syntax. In this case it templates a service to be run for every user that is ssh'd in and binds ssh-no-sleep service to each.

¹ https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Service%20Templates

Comment: Nice solution and Ubuntu is now using ssh.socket by default: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sshd-now-uses-socket-based-activation-ubuntu-22-10-and-later/30189

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this will solve what you want, but it did for my case.

After login via ssh, use:

```
    DISPLAY=:0 caffeinate bash
```

(or any other shell installed instead of `bash`)

It will prevent sleeping while you are connected to the machine via `ssh`.
You can take a look at the [caffeinate manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/caffeine/caffeinate.1.en.html).

Answer (score 0):

My own solution involves adding the following to `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`/…

```sh
if [ "$SSH_CLIENT" ] &&
     ! pstree -ps $$ |
       grep -q -- '-systemd-inhibit(' >/dev/null; then

  echo "Inhibit automatic standby"
  exec /usr/bin/systemd-inhibit \
    --what=idle --why='Interactive SSH Session' -- \
    "$SHELL" "$@"

fi
```

It works by routing/wrapping the shell on the remote through/using `systemd-inhibit` (and also making sure that there is only a single `systemd-inhibit` in the call chain, so it is not called again in case you enter a sub-shell).

Obviously, it only applies to SSH sessions with a shell.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method would be adding the following python script to the root crontab (`echo "*/1 * * * * python3 /path/to/inhibit.py" | sudo tee -a /etc/crontab`) to check if an active SSH session is present every minute and inhibit sleep:

```py
import subprocess, time, dbus  # noqa: E401
from filelock import FileLock


def run_command(command):
    result = subprocess.run(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True,
    )
    return result.stdout.decode("utf-8")


INHIBIT_FD = None
with FileLock("/tmp/inhibit_ssh.lock", 0):
    while True:
        # Run lsof command and count the number of established connections containing "code".
        # Counts vscode remote-ssh server instances. You may not require this.
        code_conns = run_command("lsof -i | grep 'code' | grep 'ESTABLISHED'").count("\n")
        # Run who command and count the number of active sessions (pts)
        ssh_conns = run_command("who | grep 'pts'").count("\n")
        total_conns = code_conns + ssh_conns

        if total_conns > 0:
            if not INHIBIT_FD:
                manager = dbus.Interface(
                    dbus.SystemBus().get_object(
                        "org.freedesktop.login1", "/org/freedesktop/login1"
                    ),
                    "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager",
                )
                res = manager.Inhibit("sleep", "sshInhibit", "SSH Active", "block")
                INHIBIT_FD = res.take()
                print("FD:", INHIBIT_FD)

            print("SSH Active")
            time.sleep(60)
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Be awared that is hibernate in lieu of suspend in my case. Please customize to yours!

Firstly, create a configuration file that placed at `/etc/configure_sleep.sh` (or anywhere that you like). This script aims to enable/disable the sleep based on your configuration (refer to [Prevent sleep/suspend when not logged in to a specific account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1101043/prevent-sleep-suspend-when-not-logged-in-to-a-specific-account/1353493#1353493)).

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script is to configure the sleep entries

TIMEOUT=60
IS_LOGIN_SCREEN=$(pgrep -u gdm gnome-session)

command=$1

if [ "${command}" = "enable" ] ; then
    sudo -Hu gdm dbus-launch dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-timeout ${TIMEOUT}
    sudo -Hu gdm dbus-launch dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-type "'hibernate'"
else
    sudo -Hu gdm dbus-launch dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
    sudo -Hu gdm dbus-launch dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-type "'nothing'"
fi
echo "I'm here"
if [ -z "${IS_LOGIN_SCREEN}" ] ; then
    echo "In user's screen."
else
    echo "This is login screen. Gnome binary will be forcedly reloaded."
    sudo killall -3 gnome-session-binary
fi
```

Secondly, rely on Prevent machine from sleeping when SSH connections are on, but, instead of masking and unmasking the sleep targets that get an annoying problem with the broadcasting keeps announce. The first script will be launched appropriately. Put this script in `/etc/pam_session.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script runs when an ssh session opens/closes,
# and changes the gnome settings, respectively.
# Inspired by: https://askubuntu.com/questions/521620/

SCRIPT_PATH="/etc/pam_session.sh"
DBUS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus

num_ssh=$(netstat -nt | awk '$4 ~ /:22$/ && $6 == "ESTABLISHED"' | wc -l)

case "$PAM_TYPE" in
    open_session)
        if [ "${num_ssh}" -gt 1 ]; then
            exit
        fi
        command=mask
        ;;

    close_session)
        if [ "${num_ssh}" -ne 0 ]; then
            exit
        fi
        command=unmask
        ;;

    *)
        exit
esac

logger "${SCRIPT_PATH}: ${command}ing sleep and suspend targets (num_ssh=${num_ssh})"

if [ ${command} = unmask ] ; then
    /etc/configure-sleep.sh "enable"
    logger "${SCRIPT_PATH}: Re-enable Auto Hibernate"
else
    /etc/configure-sleep.sh "disable"
    logger "${SCRIPT_PATH}: Disable Auto Hibernate"
fi
```

Add the script into the ssh service pam and don’t forget to make these scripts executable.

Add this line to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` under the `session` session.

```
session     optional    pam_exec.so quiet /etc/pam_session.sh
```

And make them executable.

```
chmod +x /etc/pam_session.sh
chmod +x /etc/configure-sleep.sh
```

Everything seems to fine until now. Perhaps, if you turn off the computer while ssh sessions is alive (auto sleep is off), the auto sleep will not be functional in the next power cycle. My solution delegates a service to self-enable the module.

Create a file named `99-defaultHibernate.service` and placed in `/etc/systemd/system/`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Setup default hibernaten

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
ExecStart=/etc/configure-sleep.sh enable

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Make the service affects by the following procedures.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable 99-defaultHibernate.service
sudo systemctl start 99-defaultHibernate.service
```

Please not that this approach adopts the kill of gnome binary session. It might cause potential risks or unforeseen defects.

P/s: Any indication is always welcome!